# Prove or disprove: If x = v and x = w are two solutions...

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove or disprove: If **x** = **v** and **x** = **w** are two solutions to the equation A **x** = **b**, then so is any linear combination r **v** + s **w**.

I am unsure how to do this. My approach has been to show that A(r **v** + s **w**)=**b** is a matrix equivalent to A **x** = **b**, but I am running into some issues. Any help?

Comment: Substituting gives $rb+sb=b$. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

The claim is not true. A simple counterexample:
we pick $r=s=1$, then
$$
b=A(v+w)=Av+Aw=b+b=2b.
$$
Then $b=0$?

The claim would be true if the combination is a convex one.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Falang. Consider this, though:

Choosing r = s = 1, 

b = A (v + w) = A (**x** + **x**) = A (2 **x**) = 2A **x**

And 2A **x** is simply a row operation of A **x**, making 2A **x** and A **x** equivalent matrices (and, therefore, yielding the same solutions for A **x** = **b**). 

Where does my reasoning go wrong?

Comment: I guess you meant the augmented matrix, did you? When we use augmented matrices to solve linear systems, elementary operations are fine. But this one is different. Take a one-by-one matrix as an example. x=1 and 2x=1.

Comment: Yes, I meant that [2A| **b**] is equivalent to [A| **b**] since multiplying A by 2 is just a row operation. I note your counterexample and see how it is a difficulty that I need to address, but I have trouble seeing how it is a total defeater of my reasoning. Can you help me see?

Comment: They are not equivalent. $[2A|2b]$ and $[A|b]$ are equivalent.

Comment: @Brian your equation "$... A(v + w) = A(x + x) = A(2x) ...$" is incorrect because in general we may have $v \neq w$ so you cannot replace both of them by $x$ at the same time.

Comment: Falang, but of course! Isn't it funny how sometimes you cannot see things that are right in front of you? Well, thanks for your patience with me!

Answer (score 0):

It is true for homogeneous equations of that form. In other words for $b = 0$. This is easy to see since if $v, w$ are solutions, then $A(rv + sw) = rAv + sAw = 0 + 0 = 0$. And so any linear combination $rv + sw$ is also a solution.

Comment: Thanks, Pratyush Sarkar. Please see my response to Falang above. Where does my reasoning go wrong?